# wpf user control base class problem

Tags: wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I am new to WPF and have created a WPF User Control Library

I added a Base class that looks like this

```
public class TControl : UserControl
{
}
```

and want all of my controls to inherit from it.

I have a Control called Notification which looks like

```
public partial class Notification : TControl
{
    public Notification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Works fine except when ever i recompile the hidden partial class where  InitializeComponent() is defined gets regenerated and inherits from System.Windows.Controls.UserControl

this gives me an

> Partial declarations of 'Twac.RealBoss.UserControls.Notification' must not specify different base classes

error,

is there anyway to force the generated class to inherit from my base class?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your XAML file probably has:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.Notification" .... >
```

Try changing this to:

```
<Whatever:TControl x:Class="YourNamespace.Notification" xmlns:Whatever="clr-namespace:YourNamespace" />
```

The error you are getting is because the use of UserControl in the XAML tells the compiler to produce a partial class inheriting from UserControl, instead of inheriting from your class.

Comment: A few notes: (1) `Whatever`'s name doesn't need to match anything. (2) It must be written `Whatever:BaseClass`, not the control's direct class. (3) The namespace in `xmlns:Whatever="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"` is the complete namespace path to the base class, without the base class name itself. (4) The base class does not need to be partial.

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove the ": TControl":

```
public partial class Notification : TControl
{
}
```

and write:

```
public partial class Notification
{
}
```

instead, since the base class is defined in the XAML part, as Paul wrote.

Comment: Absolutely correct, I left it in there however to remind me that it doesn’t just inherit from usercontrol. TControl doesnt do anything yet, but it might in the future

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use Hungarian notation (TControl, instead of Control), unlike Delphi it is not recommended in C# (or Java or C++). In Delphi it is only required since the language in not case sensitive.

Comment: Obviously the base class was empty because its contents are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque when you have a class defined in multiple files (a `partial class`) you do not need to repeat the base class definition - it is enough that is is defined in a single files (in this case the auto generated one).

Comment: @DannyVarod My goal in using a base class, as what seems to clearly be the author's goal, is to include shared custom functionality. This has nothing to do with the fact that the class is a partial because the x:Name variables etc. are autogenerated by VS for easier referencing.

Comment: @DenisG.Labrecque the base class is specified in the xaml, the OP's issue was that this did not compile because xaml and code did not match.